# git unable to create files when switching branch

Tags: git

I'm working on a project and I want to switch from one branch to another but this is the error message I always have:

> error: unable to create file input/restart_vectri.nc (Connection timed out)

I have like this more than 10 lines. I don't really know what the problem is. I've checked and  tried many solutions online but none of them is working.
Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: Do you have permissions to create files in the "input" directory?

Comment: So, you go into the folder where you got a git repo and when you try to create a new file you get this error?